# How to format the date in frontend AngularJS?

Tags: php, angularjs, codeigniter-3

I am getting date in below format: 
`2017-10-03 15:59:33`

I want to display it in this format: `5:15pm 10/3/2017`

How can i do this?

Comment: try moment js https://momentjs.com/

Answer (score 0):

this should work

```
{{lst.workers | date: 'H:mm MM/dd/yyyy'}}
```

Comment: {{lst.workers | date: 'H:mm MM/dd/yyyy'}} i have flow this this is not working. Please give other solution.